# Accessing a former account

Tags: icloud, apple-id

My stepmother had an @me.com email account associated with some cloud storage for a non-apple phone.  She got fed up with the non-apple phone and has given up on all smart phones, but wants to recover photos from the phone, which the tech at the store told here were in cloud storage, which she can't access without getting into her @me.com email.  I suspect that her email account is now closed, since she doesn't use or pay for it.  Is there any way to recover access to a closed email account?  Or a closed cloud account?

Comment: try and log in at iCloud.com with that email address and the last password you used. If it give you an error about no such email or account then it is unlikely. You could try calling Apple support and see if there is a way to recover the account and it's associated data. I honestly don't know if this is even possible but it sounds like it might be worth the call.

Answer (score 1):

Apple does not delete closed iCloud (Apple ID / MobileMe / iTools) accounts without a significant effort by the documented owner of each account. It’s almost certain that the account remains active and available to log in.

You’ll have to review the options at http://iforgot.apple.com and decide to follow the normal account lock out procedure or to contact Apple support.

The accounts and storage are free so don’t assume the accounts is closed based on a long time since the last log in or that there was a quick “delete” button that got pressed “on the way out the door.”